# Disable_platform_check configuration setting but getting same error

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

We are setting up a new DSE 5.1.0 cluster from opscenterd but keep facing this error.

```
ERROR: Received error from node event-subtype="MeldError" job-id="127e28d3-1b1c-4d63-8f65-f33bb3b100e0" name="Cassandra-4" ssh-management-address="192.168.150.209" node-id="7d946773-13ec-4ca7-9855-0cd032dd4a9b" event-type="error" message="OS platform (CentOS Linux, 7.4.1708, Core) is not supported for DSE 5.1.0. If absolutely necessary, this check can be turned off with the disable_platform_check configuration setting." (opscd-pool-0)

ERROR: Install job 127e28d3-1b1c-4d63-8f65-f33bb3b100e0 failed! (async-thread-macro-11)

INFO: Install job finished for node name="Cassandra-4" ssh-management-address="192.168.150.209" node-id="7d946773-13ec-4ca7-9855-0cd032dd4a9b" (async-thread-macro-10)
```

Also, we've disabled disable_platform_check and set the value to False (with capital F). But same error.

Comment: This should be fixed in 6.1.5. Please let me know if the upgrade works for you.

Comment: I am getting an error in 6.1.5 only.

Comment: The error message suggests to disable disable_platform_check in opscenterd.conf if you with to proceed without platform checks. Have you attempted to do so?

Comment: Yes I already tested with disable_platform_check : False but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The flag should be "true". Try adding this line in the opscenter.conf

```
[lifecycle_manager]
disable_platform_check = True
```